# AWS pinpoint sending Email with attachment(pdf) using .net core

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-pinpoint

I am using AWS Pinpoint in my console application. I am able to send SimpleEmail through it.
Something like this:

```
var sendRequest = new SendMessagesRequest
                {
                    ApplicationId = appId,
                    MessageRequest = new MessageRequest
                    {
                        Addresses = new Dictionary<string, AddressConfiguration>
                        {
                            {
                                demomail,
                                new AddressConfiguration
                                {
                                    ChannelType=ChannelType.EMAIL
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        MessageConfiguration = new DirectMessageConfiguration
                        {
                            EmailMessage = new EmailMessage
                            {
                                SimpleEmail = new SimpleEmail
                                {
                                    HtmlPart = new SimpleEmailPart
                                    {
                                        Charset = "UTF-8",
                                        Data = @"<html><head></head><body><h1>Amazon Pinpoint Email Test (AWS SDK for .NET)</h1></body></html>"
                                    },
                                    TextPart = new SimpleEmailPart
                                    {
                                        Charset = "UTF-8",
                                        Data = @"This email was sent using the Amazon Pinpoint API using the AWS SDK for .NET."
                                    },
                                    Subject = new SimpleEmailPart
                                    {
                                        Charset = "UTF-8",
                                        Data = @"Test Mail"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
```

But I want to include attachments in my email , for which I need to use RawEmail.
But I can't find proper documentation for sending the email with pdf attached.
Can anyone point me to it or help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Pinpoint does not support attachments. For similar use case we have copied the attachement is AWS S3 and shared the link in the email to download the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Custom Channel in Amazon Pinpoint Campaign to invoke a Lambda function, which can in turn use the raw-email function to send the pdf attachments in your email. Here is a sample code:

```
import os
import boto3
import json

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from html.parser import HTMLParser



client = boto3.client('ses')
pinpointClient = boto3.client('pinpoint')
SegmentAttributes = []
#s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3 = boto3.client("s3")



def ReadPDFFromS3Bucket():
    bucket_name ="your bucket name"
    item_name = "your pdf file.pdf"
    BUCKET_NAME = bucket_name
    KEY = item_name
    FILE_NAME = os.path.basename(KEY) 
    TMP_FILE_NAME = '/tmp/' +FILE_NAME
    s3.download_file(BUCKET_NAME, KEY, TMP_FILE_NAME)
    ATTACHMENT = TMP_FILE_NAME
    
    att = MIMEApplication(open(ATTACHMENT, 'rb').read())
    
    return att

def getCampaignTemplate(applicationID,templateName):
    
    response = pinpointClient.get_email_template(
    TemplateName=templateName
    )
    subject = response['EmailTemplateResponse']['Subject']
    return response

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        return
        #print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        return
        #print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if ('{{' in data):
            StartPos = data.index("{{")
            EndPos = data.index("}}") + 2
            SegmentAttributes.append(data[StartPos:EndPos])


def updateEndpointInactive(RECIPIENT,endpoint_id,ErrorMessage,application_id):
    response = ""

    endpoint_attribute = "EndpointStatus"
    values = ["INACTIVE"]
    response = pinpointClient.update_endpoint(
                ApplicationId=application_id,
                EndpointId=endpoint_id,
                EndpointRequest={
                    'Attributes': {
                        endpoint_attribute: values
                    }
                }
            )    
    return response
        
def sendeMailwithAttachment(SENDER,RECIPIENT,SUBJECT,BODY_TEXT,BODY_HTML,ATTACHMENT,DEBUG,endpointID,FILENAME,ApplicationId):
    CHARSET = 'utf-8'
    
    # Create a multipart/mixed parent container.
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    # Add subject, from and to lines.
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT 
    msg['From'] = SENDER 
    msg['To'] = RECIPIENT

    # Create a multipart/alternative child container.
    msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

    # Encode the text and HTML content and set the character encoding. This step is
    # necessary if you're sending a message with characters outside the ASCII range.
    textpart = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT.encode(CHARSET), 'plain', CHARSET)
    htmlpart = MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)

    # Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
    msg_body.attach(textpart)
    msg_body.attach(htmlpart)

    # Define the attachment part and encode it using MIMEApplication.
    print("Going to read attachment")
    # Add a header to tell the email client to treat this part as an attachment, and to give the attachment a name.
    att = ATTACHMENT
    att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=FILENAME)
    
    # Attach the multipart/alternative child container to the multipart/mixed parent container.
    msg.attach(msg_body)

    # Add the attachment to the parent container.
    msg.attach(att)
    response = ''
    if DEBUG == 'NO':
        try:
            #Provide the contents of the email.
            response = client.send_raw_email(
                Source=SENDER,
                Destinations=[
                    RECIPIENT
                ],
                RawMessage={
                    'Data':msg.as_string(),
                }
            )
        # Display an error if something goes wrong. 
        except ClientError as e:
            updateEndpointInactive(RECIPIENT,endpointID,e.response['Error']['Message'],ApplicationId)
            print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        else:
            print('Email sent to ' + RECIPIENT  + '! Message ID: ' + response['MessageId'])

    return response
    
def extractUserAttributes(BODY_HTML):
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(BODY_HTML)

    return SegmentAttributes

def SubstituteVariables(BODY_HTML,userAttributes,item,endpoints):
    for attribute in userAttributes:
        temp1 = attribute.replace("{{","")
        temp2 = temp1.replace("}}","")
        temp3 = temp2.split(".")
        endpointID = item
        appendString = "endpoints[item]"
        temp4 = endpoints[item]
        for field in temp3:
            temp4 = temp4[field]    
        BODY_HTML = BODY_HTML.replace(attribute,''.join(temp4))
    
    return BODY_HTML
        
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(json.dumps(event))
    endpoints = event['Endpoints']
    endpointsCount = len(endpoints)
    #Custom Data Passed: From Email id:Message Template Name:PDF Attachment 
    #From Email id: The from address that should be used for the Campaign
    # Message Template Name: The template that should be used for the campaign
    # PDF Attachment: The name of the PDF file that should be attached with the email.
    CustomData = event['Data'].split(":")
    SENDER = CustomData[0]
    TemplateName = CustomData[1]
    ObjectName = CustomData[2]
    ApplicationId = event['ApplicationId']  

    response = getCampaignTemplate(ApplicationId,TemplateName)
    
    BODY_HTML = response['EmailTemplateResponse']['HtmlPart']
    SUBJECT = response['EmailTemplateResponse']['Subject']
    BODY_TEXT = 'Find attached the requested document'
    CHARSET = 'utf-8'
    #Handle and update hard bounce
    # Attachment from S3.
    # Handle soft boucne
    BUCKET_NAME ="pinpoint.segment.bucket.binu.test"
    KEY = ObjectName
    FILE_NAME = os.path.basename(KEY) 
    TMP_FILE_NAME = '/tmp/' +FILE_NAME
    s3.download_file(BUCKET_NAME, KEY, TMP_FILE_NAME)
    ATTACHMENT = TMP_FILE_NAME
    
    att = MIMEApplication(open(ATTACHMENT, 'rb').read())
    filename=os.path.basename(ATTACHMENT)
    
    SegmentAttributes = extractUserAttributes(BODY_HTML)
    
    for item in endpoints:
        endpointID = item
        channel = endpoints[endpointID]['ChannelType']
        RECIPIENT = endpoints[endpointID]['Address']
        DEBUG = "NO"
        New_BODY_HTML = SubstituteVariables(BODY_HTML,SegmentAttributes,item,endpoints)
        sendeMailwithAttachment(SENDER,RECIPIENT,SUBJECT,BODY_TEXT,New_BODY_HTML,att,DEBUG,endpointID,filename,ApplicationId)
    
    return
```